# Function not running over all objects in the vector? (R)

Tags: r, function

I have written the following function to change a full name into first initial followed by last name:

```
names1 <- function(x) {
            z <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))[1]
            z <- substr(z,1,1)
            y <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))[2]
            paste(z,"."," ", y, sep="")
           }
```

so

```
name <- "John Doe"
names1(name)
```

returns successfully

```
"J. Doe"
```

However, when I try applying it to a vector of names, it only returns the first object(in the correct format).

Why will it not perform the function across all the objects in the vector? I did find that using `sapply` it will work correctly, but I can run other types of functions on a vector without `sapply` and have the full vector returned as output.

Comment: You hard coded the first and second elements of `unlist(strsplit(...))` using `[1]` and `[2]`. You'd have to change your function to get every first and every last name instead, or you can just keep it not-vectorized and use the suggestions from Frank's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`tstrsplit` from the data.table package makes this somewhat simpler:

```
n = c("John Doe", "Abigail Ames")

library(data.table)
x = tstrsplit(n, " ")
paste0(substr(x[[1]],1,1), ". ", x[[2]])
# [1] "J. Doe"  "A. Ames"
```

Alternately, in base you can use `Vectorize` on your function to make a vectorized version:

```
Vectorize(names1)(n)
#     John Doe Abigail Ames 
#     "J. Doe"    "A. Ames"
```

or use `sapply` to apply the function to each element and then combine the result

```
sapply(n, names1)
#     John Doe Abigail Ames 
#     "J. Doe"    "A. Ames"
```

Comment: Thanks! I've come across the data.table package a lot looking around, going to check it out once I get comfortable enough in base.